# Whats the mathematical formula for converting days into weeks

Tags: java, javascript

I don't want decimal points like `65 days = 6.2weeks`. I want `65 days = 6 weeks 1 day`

I can't use any libraries (not homework)

Comment: Do you mean Java, or JavaScript? They are two completely different languages.

Comment: 65 days is 9 weeks and 2 days...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Assuming Java (I don't know Javascript):

```
weeks    = days / 7;
days_out = days % 7;
```

Comment: "voteuping" has simple algorithm: they look if someone has big reputation, then if they can understand the answer give voteup :)

Answer (score 9):

Simply use a modulus to get the amounts of days remaining then divide the rest by 7.

```
var daysLeft = days % 7;
var weeks = Math.floor(days / 7);
```

The code above works in both Java and JavaScript (remember, other than having "Java" in the name, Java and JavaScript are two different, unrelated languages). It might be more appropriate to declare the variables as an `int` in Java however.

Answer (score 3):

In JavaScript:

```
function daysToWeeks(days)
{
    return {
        weeks: Math.floor(days/7),
        days: days % 7
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What language?

If javascript you could do it like:

```
Math.floor(65 / 7)     -> 9 weeks
```

And to get how many days into the week:

```
65 % 7                 -> 2 days
```